# Adding a custom method to a model attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is this any possible?

I'd like to have something like

```
User.avatar.to_url
```

which would then print the full URL address for the user's avatar image.

```
=> "http://url.com/images/avatars/1262694724.jpeg"
```

Of course, the avatar attribute would be an existing column on the users table which contains a long integer.

The to_url method im thinking on would be defined as:

```
def to_url
    "http://url.com/images/avatars/#{self}.jpeg"
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `avatar` is an attribute (as opposed to another model/association) then you're going to save yourself a world of trouble by just doing:

```
def avatar_url
  "http://url.com/images/avatars/#{avatar}.jpeg"
end
```

Comment: Agree, there's no good reason to be adding a to_url to your attribute.  IMO, that kind of meta-programming should be reserved for situations which have a really good justification.